# Get Strings from ArrayList and save in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that can contain 1 to 15 strings. Those strings need to be saved in my shared preferences, now I know how to iterate trough the array to get the strings. What I don't know, is there a clean way to dynamically add the strings to my shared preferences file? I could do this on a sluggish way by creating 15 strings and using an if statement to fill the shared preference, but I would like to know if there is a better way.

Thank you.

Comment: Have You tried SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet() ?

Comment: You can use a Database instead of Shared Preferences: i think is better for CRUD operation with your data.

Comment: see this excellent post  for [Save ArrayList to SharedPreferences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) instead of creating 15 keys in sharedpreferences and you can also do same by converting ArrayList to JsonArray

Comment: API 11 is not gonna work for this particular app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If its about naming, you can use something like this:

```
public static final String mPrefix = "mArray";
SharedPreferences prefs;
prefs  = this.getSharedPreferences("PREF", 0);
prefsEditor = appSharedPrefs.edit();

//mAL is your ArrayList

for(int i=0; i<mAl.size(); i++){

prefsEditor.putString(mPrefix + "-" + i, mAl.get(i));
}
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that was possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `putStringSet` method available in `SharedPreferences.Editor` to store string arrays. For example:

```
String[] array = new String[]{"this", "is", "a", "string", "array"};
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
edit.putStringSet("myKey", new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array)));
edit.commit();
```

Or **if your API is below 11** then you may convert your string array into a single string and save it just like an ordinary string. For example:

```
edit.putString("myKey", TextUtils.join(",", array));
```

and later use the following to rebuild your array from string:

```
array = TextUtils.split(sharedPrefs.getString("myKey", null), ",");
```

Comment: putStringSet available only after api 11. You can't use it in earlier android versions.

Comment: I noticed that one, I'm building for min api level 8. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly to edit the shared prefernces data you need to take the Editor Object from it so you could edit it freely so to put data in it:

```
SharedPrefernces preferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor prefEditor = preferences.edit();
prefEditor.putString("this is a key object","this is value of the key");
```

You can also put inside different kinds of object for example : boolean , int , float , double and etc....
Just look up the editor class in android developers website...

In order to read the data from the sharedPrefrences it is even more simplier

```
SharedPrefrences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
pref.getString("the key of the value");
```